# Use a graphical boot manager, like the one in Windows 10, for Windows 7 GUI

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, bootloader

I have a hard disk that has two partitions, one with Windows 7 and the other with Windows 10. I use Windows 7 mainly as a system operating system, but when I select this option by default, I lose the nice graphical interface (and get the black DOS menu to appear). Is there a way to make Windows 7 the default, but still keep the graphical bootloader interface of Windows 10?

Comment: IIRC the bootloader GUI of Windows 10 is just Windows 10 secretly pretending to be a bootloader. It boots and displays a nice interface, if you choose another OS, it reboots into it.

Comment: It's probably the case that your Windows 7 environment has 'No GUI boot' set to true. Open `msconfig`, and check the 'Boot' tab.